# How can I print using arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays

in C # I have to print an array of symbols until fat meal may delay such a thing OOO through a function I have to put the 'X' in a box of my choice. If I run the cycle, however, filled me with X across the row or column. How can I fix without two-dimensional arrays?

```
  OOO
  OXO
  OOO
```

My code:

```
static private void printArr(ref byte tail, byte[]bitmask)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Console.Write('\n');

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (change(cas, bitmask[i]) == true)
            {
                Console.Write('O');
            }
            else
                Console.Write('X');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly the most bizarre sentence I have ever read on SO.

Comment: @AntP +1. fat meal may delay. wat

Comment: I know little English I used google translator sorry

Comment: @user3223680 Unfortunately the result makes almost no sense and is impossible to understand.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    string[] arr = new string[4]; // Initialize
    arr[0] = "uno";               // First element
    arr[1] = "dos";               // Second
    arr[2] = "tres";              // Third
    arr[3] = "cuatro";            // Fourth

    // Loop over strings
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        string s = arr[i];
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    // Bonus: Loop over strings backwards
    for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        string s = arr[i];
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    }
}
```

Output

```
uno
dos
tres
cuatro

cuatro
tres
dos
uno
```

Comment: Please explain what perceived problem you interpreted from this question and how your answer solves that problem. I don't recognize _"How to for-loop over an array"_ in OP's question.